# How can I use a proper block statement with AFNetworking which passes it's responsedata to several viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, request, return, block, afnetworking

I'm working on an update for an old App of mine where I was using ASIHTTPRequest in. As the client wanted to uprade this App I've chosen to convert my excisting project to an '[ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)' one where the memory management is being handled by the App itself.

As [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) gave some errors when performing multiple requests (and the fact that ASI is outdated) I've chosen to adobt to a new library called [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). When converting this current project setup to AFNetworking I ran into a problem.

In my current setup I performed requests to a given server as follows:

```
_request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc ] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[_request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:NO];
[_request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(downloadPageHasFinished:)];
[_request setDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadPageHasFailed:)];
[_request setDelegate:self];
[_request startAsynchronous];
[ASIHTTPRequest setShouldUpdateNetworkActivityIndicator:YES];
```

Within the setup above I've been using two selectors (didFinish and didFailed) where I could catch my (non)succesful request with. Within that selector I pass back my responseData to the given parent.

```
[parent downloadCompleted:YES andContent:responseData];
```

Now I've switched to AFNetworking where I want to perform requests as well and pass back the responseData to the given parent. As AFNetworking uses blocks I'm not realy sure when or how to pass back this responseData. As the webservice gives back XML I've chosen to add the KissXML headers [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation) which is a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation. Now I'm at the point where I retrieve my complete XML document (which I want) within my block statement. But I don't know how to return this data to my specific viewcontroller (and that I can do multiple requests at the same time). My current setup for AFNetworking is as follows.

```
-(NSData *)doAFNetworkRequest:(NSURL *)url {
    __block NSData * datathingy = nil;

        AFKissXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
            NSLog(@"THE COMPLETE DOCUMENT: %@", XMLDocument);
            datathingy = [[XMLDocument description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            //the place where I can't return values

        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {


        }];

        [operation start];
    return datathingy;
}
```

When I place the "return datathingy;" within the succes block part I'm getting the error :

"Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSData *(^)(NSURLRequest *_*strong, NSHTTPURLResponse **_strong, DDXMLDocument *_*strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSURLRequest **_strong, NSHTTPURLResponse *_*strong, DDXMLDocument **_strong)'"

So how am I able to return that NSData object within my block so that the requested viewcontroller will receive the correct responseData and won't recieve nil values?

Note1:
I want to pass back the complete XML document to my viewcontrollers because the parsing is being handled in each specific viewcontroller. So only passing the responseData to the parent Viewcontroller should do it.

Note2:
I already found a [resource](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking-ASIHTTPRequest) which should convert ASI to AF directly but I'm not realy sure if these additional headers of AFNetworking would support all my previous needs which I had with ASI (i.e. caching and/or additional properties of ASIHTTPRequest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the doAFNetworkRequest method is in the viewcontroller class, you can just simply do this:

```
-(void)doAFNetworkRequest:(NSURL *)url {
    __block NSData * datathingy = nil;
    __unsafe__unretained selfPointer = self;
    AFKissXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
        NSLog(@"THE COMPLETE DOCUMENT: %@", XMLDocument);
        datathingy = [[XMLDocument description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [selfPointer parseXML:datathingy];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {


    }];

    [operation start];
```

}

But it is not good to put this request code in viewcontroller. The better way is to create a singleton class to handle all the network request. If so, in that network handler class create a protocol:

```
@protocol NetworkHandlerProtocol
-(void)requestSuccessWithData:(NSData *)data;
-(void)requestFailedWithError:(NSError *error);
```

and a delegate:

```
id<NetworkHandlerProtocol> delegate;
```

in -(void)doAFNetworkRequest:(NSURL *)url should be like this:

```
    __block NSData * datathingy = nil;

    AFKissXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
        NSLog(@"THE COMPLETE DOCUMENT: %@", XMLDocument);
        datathingy = [[XMLDocument description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //the place where I can't return values
        [self.delegate requestSuccessWithData:datathingy];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {


    }];
    [operation start];
```

then in viewcontroller, when you do the request:

```
NetworkHandler *handler = [NetworkHandler sharedHander];
handler.delegate = self;
[handler doAfNetworkRequest:url];

//some where implement the protocol methods
-(void)requestSuccessWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    //you can do something with the return data here
}
```